# JAXB: how to unmarshal a List of objects of different types inside a wrapper?

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm stucked at parsing the following xml with JAXB:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<dashboardreport name="exampleDashboard" version="6.5.6.1013" reportdate="2016-12-16T11:05:19.329+01:00" description="">
    <data>
        <incidentchartdashlet name="Incident Chart" description="" />
        <chartdashlet name="WebRequestTime" showabsolutevalues="false" />
        <chartdashlet name="WebServiceTime" showabsolutevalues="false" />
    </data>
</dashboardreport>
```

I used the following java classes to unmarshal the xml:
Dashboardreport.java

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "dashboardreport")
public class Dashboardreport {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElement(name = "chartdashlet")
    protected List<Chartdashlet> chartdashlets;

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElement(name = "incidentchartdashlet")
    protected List<Incidentchartdashlet> incidentchartdashlets;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}
```

I just want to unmarshal the xml without using a wrapper class around incidentchartdashlets and chartdashlet, cause both types differ a lot.
I only can use the XmlElementWrapper annotation once, so that only chartdashlets get filled and incidentchartdashlets is null.
Is there any solution with JAXB without using a seperate wrapper class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume your dashlet classes are defined like
`class Chartdashlet extends Dashlet` and `class Incidentchartdashlet extends Dashlet`.

Then the preferred JAXB way to handle your mixed list of dashlets would be 
by using the [`@XmlElements`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html)
annotation:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "dashboardreport")
public class Dashboardreport {

    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "data")
    @XmlElements({
        @XmlElement(name = "chartdashlet", type = Chartdashlet.class),
        @XmlElement(name = "incidentchartdashlet", type = Incidentchartdashlet.class)
    })
    protected List<Dashlet> dashlets;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "name")
    protected String name;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, Thomas! You gave me the right hint ;)

Comment: Even then, How would you downcast from `List<DashLet>` to `List<ChartDashLet>` ?

Comment: @bibliophilsagar The `List<Dashlet>` will contain `Chartdashlet` and `Incidentchartdashlet` items. Therefore down-casting it to `List<ChartDashlet>` doesn't make sense. However, you might cast an individual item, e.g. `(Chartdashlet) dashlets.get(0)` (of course after checking it with `instanceof Chartdashlet`).

Comment: Did this work for you? I get a `java.lang.ClassCastException`

Comment: @Kajzer Yes, for me it worked, without ClassCastException